# Always use EF with WCF or I could use EF directly in the clients?

Tags: entity-framework, wcf

I have an application that will connect to a Sql Server database that is installed in a server. The application will run in many client computers.

This application has a repository that uses EF to access to the database and has the logic bussiness related with the data of the database, check the information is correct, add, delete, modify and so on.

I am thinking that I have two main options.

First one, the client application, the application that will run in the client computers, can use this respository, so the application would can connect directly to the Sql Server database.

The second option, to have a server application that use this repository to connect to the databse. The clients will not use the repository, instead, will use WCF to connect with the server application to request actions and data to the database. The server would do all the work and send the result to the client through WCF.

If I am not wrong, WCF it is good when two applications has to communicate between them, for notify something between different applications or work together to do some work and so on. But in my case, it would be use just to access to the database, but the clients could do it directly if the use the repository. So I guess that use WCF to do that it would add a new layer that will make to have more work and I guess that comsume more resources.

However, this first option has a problem, if the repository has a bug and would make that the information of the databse it is incorrect or inconsistent, if I fix the problem, I would have to update all the clients to avoid they update the database incorrectly. But in some cases it would be very hard to ensure all the clients update the application to avoid the problem. At least, I don't know the way to force to a client can't run the application if it is detected a new version of the application. Are there any way to force this update?

The second option solve this problem, because I just to update the server application and all it is done. However, it makes the server to work more and need more resources. Also, I would add a new layer to the application, more work too.

So my question is, in this kind of applications, what is the best solution, first one, second one or another one that I don't know?

Is it possible to avoid that a client application runs if it is detected a new mandatory update? If it is possible, the first option would be a good solution, letting to the client applications access directly to the database?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my point of view I would use **ASP.NET WebApi 2** rather than WCF as with the first one you will be able to create a resource-oriented services over HTTP (RESTful) that can use the full features of HTTP (like URIs, request/response headers, caching, versioning, various content formats).

The idea would be to call your WebApi endpoints from the client application. In this way, all the code related to retrieve the information from your database would be defined in the API and it will be only accessible through the API.

[image]

Getting started with ASP.NET WebAPi 2: https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but in this case I have to use a new layer, so makes the system more complex. If there were a good way to force the clients to use the most recent updated version of the client application, it wouldn't be better? Because the client application will be used insede a LAN.